# How do I pass an object into one of its own functions?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have the following:

```
    public class Order
    {
        public string orderNumber { get; set; }
        public string customerName { get; set; }
        public bool isRewardsMember { get; set; }
        public string transactionNumber { get; set; }
        public List<Guid> cart { get; set; }
        public CouponResponse GeneratedCoupons = GenerateCoupons(this); <--- How could I do this?
        
        
        public CouponResponse GenerateCoupons(Order order)
        {
            string congrats = "Based on this transaction we believe you would like these coupons.";
            CouponResponse.orderGuid = order.orderGuid;
            CouponResponse.orderNumber = order.orderNumber;
            
            // blah blah blah
        }
    }
```

And I wanted to automatically create some kind of string response based on the object on generation. Could I do something like the above and just do something like this.order, or should I just use a constructor and bypass this? I want to try to have this function to be callable in case couponresponse is for whatever reason not created, or simply use this for further data collection later.

Comment: You can do that in a constructor, but not in a field initializer. But why would you have an instance method that accepts a parameter of type `Order`, but doesn't actually use `this`?

Comment: Yeah I had a feeling this would just make sense being done in the object constructor. The Order I would be trying to access is the one being created which again makes more sense in a constructor.

Comment: Your object is still being built when you are trying to access it through **This**. In this scenario, the solution is to start in the constructor itself.

Answer (score 0):

Passing an object for 2 properties seems like unnecessary coupling, but you could use the following syntax to make GeneratedCoupons do what you want:

```
public CouponResponse GeneratedCoupons => GenerateCoupons(this);
```